# ParameterizedTest gets executed before @Before function

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5, junit-jupiter

why parameterized tests are executed before setUp function?

```
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("some logic");
    }


    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"1997"})
    void myTest(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
```

Comment: can you add the import statements? I think Before should be BeforeAll or BeforeEach. Probably setUp is not called at all.

Comment: you,re right. BeforeEach is working but Before is called after my tests. they are're not exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relating to @aeberhart's comment, there is no `@Before` annotation in JUnit 5, if that's what you're using as a test runner. You need to use `@BeforeAll`, which in is the same as JUnit 4's `@BeforeClass`.

Comment: I spent a day trying to find out why the mocks used in my parameterized test were null. Turns out the `initMocks` was being called in the setup method annotated with `@Before` and it wasn't getting called at all. This Q&A helped me!